# How to make a truly public AppSync method? (Without IAM or API key)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am trying to make some of my AppSync methods public. 
By public I mean reachable directly with `curl` or `postman`. Without amplify.
I also do not want to use any API key.

Right now the only solution I found is to use a custom authorizer lambda which maintains a list of public method names and let unauthenticated users through if they try to reach these methods.

However I find this solution sub-optimal as I can think of ways to mess with it and gain access to non-public methods: abusing caching, etc...

Any one knows a better way to achieve this?

Comment: An alternative I can think about is setting up API Gateway in front of AppSync and transfer the public methods to API Gateway. Again that feels a bit hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting AWS support they confirmed that a pure public function is not achievable with AppSync.

The solutions would then be:

- Authorizer lambda that accepts unauthenticated users (not optimal)
- Have API Gateway as a front with public methods and use it as a proxy to AppSync private methods.